# Has there been a recent update to the yahoo_fin library; I'm getting an assertion error?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I've been using the yahoo_fin library for several weeks (the same version from 2021 with no new updates). My program doesn't work now, but neither does a simple request. I'm getting an assertion error.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Notebook/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/ChatExample.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = get_quote_data(symbol)
  File "C:\Users\Notebook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\stock_info.py", line 961, in get_quote_data
    valid.""")
AssertionError: Invalid response from server.  Check if ticker is
                              valid.
```

Here is the basic code I'm trying to work with.

```py
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import *

symbol = 'C'
data = get_quote_data(symbol)
print(data)
```

When I go to the source library, I've tried extracting just the URL it uses and that doesn't work either. I've tried multiple stickers from the most well known stocks.

```py
site = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=" + ticker
```

This is the return:

```json
{"finance":{"result":null,"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","description":"Invalid Crumb"}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change v7 in your URL to v6 and it should work, at least for now. I found this solution on GitHub searching on the error.

Comment: I actually contacted the author and he said he will be fixing the code, so I can't mark your answer as the correct one but it is a work around. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

Just use this instead.

```
site = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/" + ticker + "?modules=summaryDetail"
```

Comment: Does this one still work right now? I get {
    "finance": {
        "result": null,
        "error": {
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "description": "Invalid Cookie"
        }
    }
}

Comment: I receive a `401` as well

Answer (score 0):

I've contacted the author on LinkedIn and he will be updating the library in the next couple of weeks.

I'm using Pycharm, so when I get the error, I'm also given a hyperlink to the error:

```py
File "C:\Users\Notebook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\stock_info.py", line 961, in get_quote_data
```

Click on that link and it should take you the library package and you can do what Dan G mentioned above by changing the V7 in the link to V6 as shown below.

```py
site = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v6/finance/quote?symbols=" + ticker
```